# Разбор ошибки дампа Базы SQL ( строки /*!40101 SET)

Tags: sql

Один раз при переезде не другой сервер и при импорте БД появилась ошибка.

```html
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */
Відповідь MySQL: Документація

#1231 - Variable 'character_set_client' can't be set to the value of 'NULL'
```

По подсказкам службы поддержки проблемму удалось решить удалением всех строк которые содержат /*!40101 из дампа БД.
Поскажите кто знаком из SQL. Что я вообще сделал? 
И что означают эти цифры  /*!40101?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Технически текст между `/*` и `*/` является [комментарием](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comments.html).

Вариант начинающийся с `/*!` (или `/*!число`) имеет особое значение для mysql. Такой комментарий уже не является комментарием, а подставляется в запрос к mysql как есть. В то же время другие парсеры SQL будут считать это комментарием. Вот под видом такого хака для написание портируемых запросов это было сделано. Последующее число рассматривается как ограничение минимальной версии mysql. Так, текст вида:

```
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */
```

при выполнении в mysql версии выше 4.1.1 будет интерпретирован как обычный запрос:

```
SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT
```

Но проигнорирован другими реализациями и более старыми версиями mysql.

Синтаксис `@variable` - это переменная в mysql. Очевидно её ранее в этой сессии необходимо было установить, для чего обычно в начале дампа есть соответствующие команды. Если таковых не было - то вы как раз получите такую ошибку.

Настройка же `CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT` отвечает за используемую клиентским приложением кодировку.